# PCA with colorbar

Tags: matlab, pca, colorbar

I have [this data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uoumpt4q7wgjwll/data.mat?dl=0) of which I want to make a principal component analysis.

In particular for each data point I want to associate a color.

This is my code:

```
    for ii=1:size(SBF_ens,1)
        SBF(ii) = SBF_ens(ii, max(find(SBF_ens(ii,:)~=0)) );  %value at the moment of the measurement
    end

    %matrix of data
    toPCA =[
        wind_trend_72h_ens-nanmean(wind_trend_72h_ens);
        wind_trend_24h_ens-nanmean(wind_trend_24h_ens);
        wind_trend_12to18h_ens-nanmean(wind_trend_12to18h_ens);
        wind_trend_0to12h_ens-nanmean(wind_trend_0to12h_ens);
        wind_trend_last6h_ens-nanmean(wind_trend_last6h_ens);
        Mwind12h_ens-nanmean(Mwind12h_ens);
        Mwind24h_ens-nanmean(Mwind24h_ens);
        SBF-nanmean(SBF)]';

    variables = { 'wt72h','wt24h','wt12to18h','wt0to12h','wtLast6h','Mw12h', 'Mw24h', 'SBF'}; %labels 

    %PCA algorithm    
    C = corr(toPCA,toPCA);   

    w = 1./var(toPCA);

    [wcoeff,score,latent,tsquared,explained] = pca(toPCA,'VariableWeights',w);

    coefforth = diag(sqrt(w))*wcoeff;

    metric=decstd_ens; %metric for colorbar

hbi=biplot(coefforth(:,1:2),'scores',score(:,1:2),'varlabels',...
    variables,'ObsLabels', num2str([1:length(toPCA)]'),...
'markersize', 15);

    %plotting
    cm = autumn;
    colormap(cm);


    for ii = length(hbi)-length(toPCA):length(hbi)
        userdata = get(hbi(ii), 'UserData');

        if ~isempty(userdata)

             indCol = ceil( size(cm,1) * abs(metric(userdata))/max(abs(metric)) );%maps decstd between 0 and 1 and find the colormap index


            if indCol==0     %just avoid 0                    
                indCol=1;
            end

            col = cm(indCol,:); %color corresponding to the index

                set(hbi(ii), 'Color', col); %modify the dot's color


        end
    end
    for ii = 1:length(hbi)-length(toPCA)-1 %dots corresponding to the original dimensions are in black
        set(hbi(ii), 'Color', 'k');
    end

    c=colorbar;
    ylabel(c,'decstd') %is this true?
    xlabel(['1^{st} PCA component ',  num2str(explained(1)), ' of variance explained'])
    ylabel(['2^{nd} PCA component ', num2str(explained(2)), ' of variance explained'])
```

The resulting figure is the following:
[image]

Everything is fine except for the colorbar range. In fact `decstd` has values between 0 and 2. Actually I do not understand at all what the values on the colorbar are.
Does anyone understand it?

Is it possible to rethrive the data in the colorbar? So to understand what they are?

Comment: what is `hbi`? Where is it declared / assigned to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
size(autumn)
```

shows you that the default length of the `autumn` colourmap (actually of all the colourmaps) is `64`. When you call `colorbar`, by default it will use tick labels from `1` to `n` where `n` is the length of your colourmap, in this case `64`.

If you want the mapping of the colourbar ticklabels to match the mapping that you used to get your data to fit between `1` and `64` (i.e. this line of yours `indCol = ceil( size(cm,1) * abs(metric(userdata))/max(abs(metric)) );`), then you will need to set that yourself like this

```
numTicks = 6;
cAxisTicks = linspace(min(metric), max(metric), numTicks); % or whatever the correct limits are for your data
caxis([min(metric), max(metric)]);
set(c,'YTick', cAxisTicks );
```

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem with this: `caxis([min(metric), max(metric)])
set(c,'YTick',linspace(min(metric), max(metric),6));`

Comment: I'll add that to the answer